# 2-way SSL - is it possible to accept multiple client certs on one IIS site?

Tags: tls, iis

A client has asked us to build an API which requires two-way SSL.  Will we be able to expose that same API to other clients with different certificates?  Or will we have to set up a different endpoint for each different client certificate?

We'll be hosting it in IIS, and both parties will be using proper CAs (I mean like Thawte, not self-signed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Side note: this question is probably better suited to ServerFault.

Yes you can! There's full steps for setting everything up [here](https://medium.com/@hafizmohammedg/configuring-client-certificates-on-iis-95aef4174ddb), but the short version is that you need to use the IIS "Configuration Editor" tool, in the Client Certificate Mapping Authentication section

> system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication

and then go into the "oneToOneMappings" UI and hit "Add" for each user. Specify their cert (and user details), and there you go: their cert will now map to a user that web applications or other access-controlled resources can identify and authorize (or not).

Answer (score 2):

You can surely do this with open source. So I think it is possible with IIS as well. Assuming you mean ** TLS Client Authentication** (2-way SSL).

With Apache2 Client Authentication works by exposing the authenticated user's data to your web application. Here is a sample app I put together to [demo TLS Client Authentication](https://github.com/felin-arch/tls-client-auth). Here are the relevant pieces.

Config to use TLS Client Auth (this works w/ a single root, but you can also use multiple CAs by specifying `SSLCACertificatePath` instead of `SSLCACertificateFile`):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ...
        SSLVerifyClient optional
        SSLVerifyDepth 1
        SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/ssl/private/ca.crt"
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    ...

</VirtualHost>
```

The `SSLOptions +StdEnvVars` exposes the client certificate's data as an environment variable to your PHP script. You can then access it like so.

```
<?php
  echo $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN'];
  echo $_SERVER['SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN'];
?>
```

This way you can verify which client is authenticating in your web application. I am not familiar with how IIS handles these cases, but I think it is supported in some way. The key is to have it configured in a way to use multiple CAs when authenticating the clients. [This](https://medium.com/@hafizmohammedg/configuring-client-certificates-on-iis-95aef4174ddb) post should help.

Alternatively, you can check out [other authentication methods](https://www.securitydrops.com/the-web-api-authentication-guide/) that provide a similar level of protection that TLS Client Certificates do.

Comment: That's a really useful summary of other authentication methods - thanks!